# Find all $x \in \mathbb{Z+}$ s.t. $x^2+2x-3$ is prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

It is given as an exercise question in the book titled "An Introduction to Essential Algebraic Structures" By Martyn R. Dixon, Leonid A. Kurdachenko, Igor Ya Subbotin.

I feel there should be infinite number of values. 
Manually, only one values found by me:
(i) $x=2 \implies 5$.

Comment: Hint: $x^2+2x-3=(x+3)(x-1)$

Comment: $117$ is not prime $9\mid117$

Comment: And 5 is the only one...

Comment: @robjohn But, what help or insight the factorization offers is not clear to me.

Comment: @jiten: if both $|x+3|$ and $|x-1|$ are greater than one then $(x+3)(x-1)$ cannot be a prime. So there are very few cases in which $x^2+2x-3$ can be a prime for $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Understood the point made by robjohn. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\Bbb Z$, an element $p$ is prime iff it is irreducible, that is, iff the only divisors of $p$ are $p$ and $\pm 1$.

If you factorise your quadratic, you get  $x^2 + 2x - 3 = (x+3)(x-1)$. Applying the above criterion, you need one of these factors to be $1$ (since in the question you are looking in $\Bbb Z^+$). Indeed, this means that $x = 2$ gives $(2 + 3)(2 - 1) = 5$, and since this is the only positive integer which makes one of these factors $1$, this is the only $x \in \Bbb Z^+$ making $x^2 + 2x - 3$ prime.

Comment: Thanks for that. Sorry, for silly question, but I thought that primes are positive only, so can I look for values of $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ also?

Comment: @jiten: primes are positive, but if both $x+3$ and $x-1$ are negative, their product is positive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I wish I could ask some other questions on primes from you now.

Comment: Well, if $p$ is prime then $-p$ has essentially the same divisibility properties (since $\pm 1$ are units, in more general terminology). We call $p, -p$ associates. But most authors define primes to be positive.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x^2+2x-3=(x+3)(x-1)$, $x^2+2x-3$ can only be prime if $x-1=1$ or $x+3=-1$. Otherwise, $x^2+2x-3$ is composite or negative.

Comment: Can you please give me a value of $x$ for which $x^2 +2x -3$ is negative and not composite.

Comment: It depends on your definition of composite. $-2$ cannot be written as the product of standard [prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number), since standard primes are greater than $1$ (hence positive). However, including $-1$ among the primes allows for non-unique prime factorizations. That is why the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) usually only deals with integers greater than $1$.